# Current file size when using GZIPOutputStream

Tags: java

I am writing compressed data to disk using GZIPOutputStream in an asynchronous manner

I want to know the size of data already written so I can close the file once it reaches a limit

```
ByteBuffer src;
//..
//data added to src here
//..
File theFile = new File("hello.gz");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(theFile);
GZIPOutputStream zs = new GZIPOutputStream(fos);
BufferedWriter zipwriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(zs, "UTF-8"));

(while_more_data)
{
   zipwriter.write(src.get());
   // check current file size here and close file if limit is reached
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your `FileOutputStream` into another output stream that is able to count the number of bytes written, like [`CountingOutputStream`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/CountingOutputStream.html) provided by third party library [Jakarta Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/), or [`CountingOutputStream`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/CountingOutputStream.html) from [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).

The implementation could be something like:

```
ByteBuffer src;
//..
//data added to src here
//..
File theFile = new File("hello.gz");
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(theFile);
     CountingOutputStream cos = new CountingOutputStream(fos);
     GZIPOutputStream zs = new GZIPOutputStream(cos);
     BufferedWriter zipwriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(zs, "UTF-8"))) {

    (while_more_data) {
        zipwriter.write(src.get());
        zipwriter.flush(); // make sure, data passes cos
        if (cos.getByteCount() >= limit) {
            // limit reached
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Guava also has [`CountingOutputStream`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/io/CountingOutputStream.html).

Comment: You can also use [DataOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) which doesn't require any library. It has a `.size()` method which will return the number of bytes that have been written.

Answer (score 0):

**Or** if you don't wan't to pull in an entire library like [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) or [Commons-IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/), you can just extend the [GZIPOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html) and obtain the data from the associated [Deflater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html) like so:

```
public class MyGZIPOutputStream extends GZIPOutputStream {

  public GZIPOutputStream(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
      super(out);
  }

  public long getBytesRead() {
      return def.getBytesRead();
  }

  public long getBytesWritten() {
      return def.getBytesWritten();
  }

  public void setLevel(int level) {
      def.setLevel(level);
  }
}
```